# React Js not going to src on ../

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a css file in my project which is is the src folder but it can't see it when I type ../styles/Cust.css it keeps trying to look in the folder that I'm calling the css from. Why is it doing this double dot should mean root but its not registering it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing `../../../style/Cust.css` which isn't standard but it works if you can suggest a better way of doing this comment on this answer please

Answer (score 2):

```
..
```

is the parent folder

```
/
```

is root

use

```
/src/styles/Cust.css
```

Comment: I tried that then i got the error ./src/components/Parts/Content/MainContent.js
Module not found: You attempted to import /styles/Cust.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.  its not outside the src folder so i dont know why it says it is

Comment: how are you including the css file?

Comment: its just inside styles that in src which is root

Comment: ./ is different of  /  remove your dot

Answer (score 1):

Better way of doing it by putting your styles folder in root i.e. on the same level of src folder. And include your css file in index.html like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">
```

By doing this you do not need to import css file in every component, you can simply apply css class names and other css attributes.

For reference: [Here](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-set-background-image) is a simple github repository. I have created a css file in separate folder and used it.  Hope it helps.